# ApolloError in Firefox when doing a GraphQL mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, graphql

I am attempting to follow along to a tutorial found [here](https://zoejoyuliao.medium.com/django-graphql-react-2-integrate-graphql-into-your-react-project-71fa74f1cb00) to create a simple Django + React + GraphQL app. My queries are working as intended, but using a mutation results in a `ApolloError` being thrown.

My mutation for adding a user is as follows:

```js
const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser ($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!){
    createUser (firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName){
      id
      firstName
      lastName
  }
}
`;
```

And my mutation function is as follows:

```js
export function CreateUser() {
    
  let firstName, lastName;
  const [createUser] = useMutation(CREATE_USER);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          createUser({ variables: {
            firstName: firstName.value,
            lastName: lastName.value
          } });    
          firstName.value = '';
          lastName.value = '';
          window.location.reload();      
        }}
        style = {{ marginTop: '2em', marginBottom: '2em' }}
        >     
        <label>First Name: </label>
        <input
          ref={node => {
            firstName = node;
          }}
        style={{ marginRight: '1em' }}
        />     
        <label>Last Name: </label>
        <input
          ref={node => {
            lastName = node;
          }}
          style={{ marginRight: '1em' }}
        />
        <button type="submit" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>Add a User</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Attempting to send a mutation causes the following error to appear in the developer's console:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

Upon closer inspection of the call stack, the error seems to occur when calling `createUser` in the `onSubmit` attribute. I've already tried clearing my cache and cookies. This code also seems to only have issues in Firefox, as it works in both Chromium and Edge.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what does your network tab show?

Comment: Looks like the issue was with the 'window.location.reload()` line in the `onSubmit` attribute. With this line, submitting the form would cause multiple GETs to different static JS files with status code 304. Upon removing the `window.location.reload()` line, a GET to `/` and `vendors~main.chunk.js` with status code 304 is sent initially, followed by POSTs to the GraphQL URI (with status code 200) and everything works as intended. Any advice on why this occurs?

Comment: location.reload is very primitive, refetch query should be used (not poll interval), separate component for form and list, useState for fields ... follow some better react/apollo tutorials